# Generate Terminal Service license report and send automatically via Email

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, terminal-services

Before sending License reports to Mail . I did try this directly on the license server as a means fo debugging `PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_TSLicenseReport -Name GenerateReportEx`  and it returned the following

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
FileName         : PER-USER_20160524-213433-748.dat
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :
```

Suspecting the license server database is corrupt. Any recommendations ? Will a database rebuild be required at this point. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John zuh.

This is not a PS issue or code issue, which is what we are here to help with.
Well, you have not shown your PS report and mail message code / issues with it.

It is a potential environment issue as noted by you. So, this would not be the correct forum for this question. I'd suggest SuperUser and following this discussion and answer.

> The problem A license database for remote desktop in Windows 2012 got
>   corrupted as helpdesk executes several times an script in powershell
>   used to install licenses for Windows 2008 R2 and then for Windows 2012
>
> https://superuser.com/questions/1028042/how-to-fix-a-corrupted-rds-licenses-database

So, since you already suspect environment issues, then correct those in the most prudent methods supported, if it is beyond what the above addresses.

***Update for resources***

As noted there are additional resources to help you. Take the default reporting class, generate the report and attach that to an email either as a text file or html. At that point, you are just using the basic of the Send-MailMessage cmdlet.

Win32_TSLicenseReport class
Provides instances of Remote Desktop Services Per User client access license (RDS Per User CAL) usage reports that are generated on the Remote Desktop license server, and methods for license report generation, fetch, and delete operations.

```
[dynamic, provider("Win32_WIN32_TERMSERVLICENSING_Prov"), AMENDMENT]
class Win32_TSLicenseReport
{
    string   FileName;
    uint32   LicenseUsageCount;
    uint32   InstalledLicenses;
    DATETIME GenerationDateTime;
    uint32   ScopeType;
    string   ScopeValue;
    uint32   Version;
};
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/win32-tslicensereport

GenerateReport method of the Win32_TSLicenseReport class

[GenerateReport is no longer available for use as of Windows Server 2012. Instead, use GenerateReportEx.]

This method is not supported.

Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008: Generates a current per user license usage report on the Remote Desktop license server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/generatereport-win32-tslicensereport

As per your comment this one you already know about...

Get-WmiObject Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack class

```
[dynamic, provider("Win32_WIN32_TERMSERVLICENSING_Prov"), AMENDMENT]
class Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack
{
  uint32   KeyPackId;
  string   Description;
  uint32   KeyPackType;
  uint32   ProductType;
  string   ProductVersion;
  uint32   ProductVersionID;
  uint32   TotalLicenses;
  uint32   IssuedLicenses;
  uint32   AvailableLicenses;
  DATETIME ExpirationDate;
  uint32   AccessRights;
  string   TypeAndModel;
```

};

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/win32-tslicensekeypack

Get RDS licenses issued to all trusted domains

This script will get the RDS licenses issued from the local computer that have been issued to all Trusted domains. The variables on lines 1 through 12 needs to be modified to fit your environment.The below snippet generates the new report. If you don't want it to generate it for 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RDS-licenses-issued-to-87389868

```
$NewReport = Invoke-Wmimethod -class win32_tslicensereport -name generatereport -argumentlist @(3,0)
```

FetchReportEntries method of the Win32_TSLicenseReport class
Retrieves details of Remote Desktop Services Per User client access licenses (RDS Per User CALs) from the report. Each entry represents a RDS Per User CAL that is currently in use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/fetchreportentries-win32-tslicensereport

You don't say what server version you are on, but. you could  also use the Terminal Services Licensing Reporter Tool (Lsreport.exe).
Here you would need to write a custom script to run Lsreport.exe tool and parse its output.

You can download the old W2K3ResKit to get it. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657

```
lsreport /?

Write information about licenses granted by Terminal Server License Servers.

lsreport [/F filename] [/D start [end]] [/T] [/W] [/?] [serverlist]

  /F filename         Directs output to be written to a file named filename.
                      (filename defaults to lsreport.txt)
  /D start [end]      Prints only licenses that were in force between start
                      and end.  (end defaults to today)
  /T                  Directs only temporary licenses to be written.
  /W                  Directs the hardware id to be written to the text file. (.Net Servers Only)
  /?                  Prints this program summary.
  serverlist          A list of license servers to query.  If not specified,
                      a list will be obtained from a domain controller.

Examples:
  lsreport
  lsreport /T NTLS-1 NTLS-2
```

See also:
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-monitor-terminal-services-licenses-with-lsreportexe/1058268

See also:

Manage Remote Desktop Licensing by using Windows PowerShell
https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2010/04/07/manage-remote-desktop-licensing-by-using-windows-powershell

Remote Desktop Services Provider for Windows PowerShell
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee791871(v=ws.10)

Comment: Anyway appreciate the recommendations. I found a workaround using Get-WmiObject  Win32_TSLicenseKeyPack . This Object gave me a more detailed statistic. I just need to figure how to format the results and output to Email.